# Is azure devtest lab available for service fabric clusters?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-devtest-labs

I know that there is party service fabric clusters but it is public. I do not want to use it.

Is there an azure devtest lab that I can provision so that I can author services locally on my machine but test my services in the cloud with azure devtest labs so that we can do near production ready testing in the labs?

Or is azure devtest lab is not built for this kind of service fabric service authoring and testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DevTest Labs is designed to enable the creation of individual VMs for development and testing. It does not support creating clusters of VMs as is required for Service Fabric or the Azure Container Service.

If your goal is to be able to stand up a cluster when you need it for testing and then tear it down afterwards, most people accomplish that by creating an ARM template that describes their test environment, then using scripts to create/delete that environment on-demand as part of their CI flow.

Comment: Is this still the case? Because I found following info at this link: Service Fabric artifacts in Azure DevTest Lab
We have made it possible for you to using Azure DevTestLab to quickly setup Service Fabric development environments. You can read more about Azure DevTestLab here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/devtest-lab/

Comment: Yes. The development environment referred to here is still a single machine. It just has the Service Fabric SDK and tools preinstalled.

Comment: Is there any plan for Microsoft to change this, and is the only other option for completely isolating these Azure services to create a second Azure subscription?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "completely isolating these services". Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can currently bring an ARM template (which could be containing a Service Fabric cluster) and deploy it within a DevTest Lab. VMs that are deployed as part of this template will have a corresponding Lab VM created and be able to participate as a normal VM of a lab (auto-start/stop, cost, etc). Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-lab/devtest-lab-create-environment-from-arm).

Service Fabric cluster specific support is currently in development. You will be able to auto-start/stop the entire cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This is now live: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devtestlab/2018/01/08/service-fabric-in-devtest-lab-environments/.

I'm trying to get it to work :)